# Login with facebook issue: app not active

Tags: android, flutter, facebook

How can I resolve the "App not active" error in my Flutter app when implementing Facebook login? I'm currently able to log in with the account I added as tester in the Roles section of my Facebook app, but for other users, they encounter the "App not active" error.

> App not active. This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue. You will be able to log in when the app is reactivated.

I am using the `flutter_facebook_auth` package to handle the login with facebook feature. Here is the relevant code:

```
class FbAuth {
  Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook() async {
    // Trigger the sign-in flow
    final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(
      permissions: ['email'],
    );

    // Create a credential from the access token
    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.token);

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
  }
}
```

I've already checked [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview), and it appears that my app should not require review since I'm only requesting "public profile" and "email" permissions.

> Apps may ask for the following two permissions from any person without submitting for review by Facebook:
>
> public profile
>
> email
>
> To ask for any other permission, your app will need to be reviewed by Facebook before these permission become visible in the Login Dialog to the public who're logging into your app with Facebook.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Review or not, you still need to publish your app, before other people without a role in it, will be able to use it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release

Comment: @CBroe I've gone through the documentation you shared, and App Review appears to be a necessary step in the app publishing process. As part of this review, business verification is required. However, I don't own a business. Does this mean that I won't be able to implement 'Login with Facebook' in my application?

Comment: It looks like Facebook has been pushing into that direction recently, yes.